# Date Cast/Convert

Tags: sql, casting

I get errors like "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." All I have to do is add a WHERE clause where I compare values having (datetime, null) format (like 2014-07-29 00:00:00.000) and values having (decimal (8,0), null) format (like 20140723).

I tried to cast both these values as varchar, tried to cast one of them as date - nothing works.

At the same time, when I ran a previous query without the WHERE clause, the following join condition worked perfctly:

on cast(DATE_1 as date)= cast(cast(DATE_2 as varchar) as date)

Any ideas? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Since the problem was in *the `WHERE` clause*, you should really need to post *the `WHERE` clause*

Comment: post all your query please.